# How to stop Azure database endless loop session

Tags: loops, azure, azure-sql-database, infinite-loop

Last night I might have started an endless loop on my Azure website, copying data in the database. Its about 24 hours ago, and my tables still keep growing. Can I stop or will it burn out at some time? My Azure subscription cpu time is totally maxed out.

I even unlinked my database from the website, but the table keeps growing a couple of rows per second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the datatype on a column for loop to run into an error and stop. Messed up. CPU time at 518% :S Good thing Azure is so cheap :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you stop it as soon as possible using the portal. There are very few reasons that would cause it to 'burn out' and be recycled. The Azure Fabric Controller has no way of knowing that it is a rogue process, so it will never step in.

Comment: How can I stop it in the portal? If I delete the website, will that cause the loop to end?

Comment: There is a stop button (square) at the bottom of the page - on Azure Websites.

Comment: No not on my portal. Only manage domain, delete and webmatrix. But thanks for your quick answer

Comment: I assume you're using a Windows Azure Web Sites? If so, you should see "browse", "stop" and "restart" to the left of "manage domain" and "delete". If you don't see this, you may not be an admin. Please ask an admin to stop your site ASAP before you run into billing issues ;)